# XmlSerializer throws an exception on enum

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

With the following Code the `XmlSerializer` throws an expection because `Foo` contains two Properties with the same name of the enum `EnumSameName`.

Framework .NET 4.0

```
public class Bar1
{
    public enum EnumSameName
    {
        a
    }

    public EnumSameName MyBar1Enum { get; set; }
}

public class Bar2
{
    public enum EnumSameName
    {
        b
    }

    public EnumSameName MyBar2Enum { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        MyEnum1 = new Bar1();
        MyEnum2 = new Bar2();
    }

    public Bar1 MyEnum1 { get; set; }

    public Bar2 MyEnum2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now try to serialize `Foo`

```
var parameter = new Foo();
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(parameter.GetType()); 
// ERROR System.InvalidOperationException: [...]
```

After rename one of the `EnumSameName` everything works as expected.

Where does this error come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message in question should read

> Types 'Bar2.EnumSameName' and 'Bar1.EnumSameName' both use the XML
>   type name, 'EnumSameName', from namespace ''. Use XML attributes to
>   specify a unique XML name and/or namespace for the type.

Have a look at

[XML Namespace Collisions, XmlNodeList and Deserialization, and More](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164122.aspx)

You can try to change the code to

```
[XmlRoot("Bar1", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/Bar1")]
public class Bar1
{
    [XmlRoot("Bar1EnumSameName", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/Bar1")]
    public enum EnumSameName
    {
        a
    }

    public EnumSameName Mode { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot("Bar2", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/Bar2")]
public class Bar2
{
    [XmlRoot("Bar2EnumSameName", Namespace = "http://example.com/schemas/Bar2")]
    public enum EnumSameName
    {
        b
    }

    public EnumSameName Mode { get; set; }
}
```

As an after thought, just adding the [XmlRoot documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute.aspx)

> Controls XML serialization of the attribute target as an XML root
>   element.